Builds in Store Disappears
When I upload a build to App Store Connect, it appears in TestFlight -> Builds section for a few minutes while it's processing, and then it disappears. There's no trace of it ever having been there. Any ideas? I upload using XCode.
The Xcode logs say it's been uploaded
Xcode Version 15.4
